# E-Mails of PHPMailer still getting into SPAM on some clients even after adding SPF-record

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, tls1.3

So I developed an automated Mailing System through which I send automated e-mails in PHP using the PHPMailer Extension.

First, most of the e-mails I've sent with the PHPMailer dropped into the spam of several clients, a well-known issue. I've checked with my host and we created an SPF record; and the result improved a lot.

Now by coincidence, I've found that some clients still seem to drop messages received via the PHPMailer script into their Spam folder. If I send the same e-mail manually, it doesn't happen, so it seems to be related to PHPMailer; so I must be doing something wrong.

The configs / code I'm currently using are / is :

```
$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Host = $host; // verified with my host 
$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->Username = 'mymail@mydomain.com'; // verified with my host 
$mail->Password = 'mypassword'; // verified with my host 

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = true;
$mail->setFrom( 'mymail@mydomain.com', 'This is the Header of the E-Mail' );
$mail->addAddress( 'recipientsmail@hisdomain.com', '' );
$mail->isHTML( true );
$mail->Subject = 'This is the Subject of the E-Mail';
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Body = 'HTML Content of the E-Mail';
$mail->send();
$mail->SmtpClose();
```

Please note that my hosting provider does not support any DKIM signature authentication; and I've also verified the correct reverse DNS lookup with my provider.

What am I missing folks?

I interestingly came about [this](https://www.mailgun.com/blog/which-smtp-port-understanding-ports-25-465-587/) post here; which writes that "IANA has reassigned a new service to this port [465], and it should no longer be used for SMTP communications."

The article recommends the use of `tls` and port `587` should be the default approach. Is this maybe the issue; or am I missing something out on PHPMailer? I just wanna be sure before switching anything, as I'm not at all an expert in the area of e-mails.. And well, I've never heard about this port issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether mail ends up in spam is very difficult to control. Implementing SPF and DKIM can help, but still provide no guarantees. If it was easy to bypass spam filters, spammers would do it, and they would not be spam filters! There's [an article in the PHPMailer wiki about avoiding spam filters](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Improving-delivery-rates,-avoiding-spam-filters) that you may find helpful. The headers in a received message will often tell you *why* a message has been put in the spam folder, for example listing the spamassassin rules it matched.

You say it works "manually", but is that sending from the same place (e.g. on your local machine)? You can get the raw text of messages sent through each route and compare them to see what's different (other than obvious things like message IDs).

That MailGun article is outdated. Since then, [RFC8314](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8314.html) has not only "undeprecated" port 465, it's now recommended as the default because it eliminates a possible attack vector in the pre-encryption stage that SMTP+STARTTLS uses on port 587. Unfortunately it also makes it harder to debug from PHP, and denies the chance to do opportunistic encryption when encryption is not requested explicitly, so it's not the default in PHPMailer (yet).

Comment: Thanks a lot! So you say that the configuration I'm using is indeed ideal (465 + SSL and prefer TLS if available) ? And yes, by manually I mean the same machine, but by writing an e-mail which only holds text, and no real HTML tables etc. as the one sent via the PHPMailer, and sending it from a mail app like Apple Mail.

Comment: What I still wonder though is : my host says they don't support DKIM sugnatures out of the box. Is it still possible to use DKIM via PhpMailer, if I follow the phpmailer docs, while still also sending my emails with the code shown above?

Comment: There are many reasons for messages to be classified as spam, and the content is one of them. HTML messages are more likely to be considered spam that plain text ones, but you can eliminate that by testing with a simple "hello world" plain-text body sent from PHPMailer (use your example code as-is, and comment out the call to `isHTML`). It is possible to do DKIM signing with PHPMailer, but it is better if you can get your mail server to do it.

Comment: Thx again for ur hints. The thing is that I can't really test it, in some gmail accounts it drops into the spam, in others it doesn't. It even started to drop into the spam folder of clients with which I've already communicated with manually (and not programmatically with PHPMailer) sent e-mails; so I supposed the issue must be with PHPMailer. I however found out now that the prod HTML e-mails still had tons of HTML comments in it; like half of the e-mail were comments. No clue if that's bad, but took em off, it's my only guess for now..

Comment: Remember that source IP, sending history, and from address are also major factors in whether things are classified as spam, and they are all independent of your content. Do check the received headers on gmail though – while their classification may be poor, they do at least tell you what it's doing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the mentioned "from addresses"? I suppose that's missing in my code above? Also, if you have any link to any reasonable guide which can be used to understand gmail headers (because I've obtained a sample e-mail in my gmail spam folder but cannot interpret it), that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: And also, one question I had pending in my mind; for which you're probably the best person to ask: I just did some anti-spam test using my PHPMailer script and they all passed except for the Gmail and the Outlook client (so indeed a biggie); the main issue being the missing DKIM authentication. You said it's better if the host does use DKIM, but mine does not, and will only implement it by the end of the year. Is it wise to implement DKIM with PHPMailer in this case with many mail clients going well now; or do you consider it to be risky? Would you do it in my case or not?